# How to pass returned variables to other methods in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a returned value to another function. I want the function to be reusable.

```
EDUC_A = '2016Census_G16A_AUS.csv'
EDUC_B = '2016Census_G16B_AUS.csv'
def read_files(EDUC_A,EDUC_B):
    with open(EDUC_A, 'r') as f, open(EDUC_B, 'r') as f1:
        line = []
        for i in f:
            line.append(i.split(","))
        line2 = []
        for j in f1:
            line2.append(j.split(","))
        
        line[0] = line[0][1:] + line2[0][1:]
        line[1] = line[1][1:] + line2[1][1:]
        
        temp = []
        for i in line[1]:
            temp.append(int(i))
        line[1] = temp
        
        temp = []
    return line
```

I want to pass the returned variable line into this function:

```
def create_categories(line):
   #Here I want to use the variable line but not sure how
   
    main_category = []
    temp1 = []
    
    #SPlit the lists into category of male, female, people
    n = len(line[1])//3
    for i in range(0,len(line[0]),n):
        for j in range(i,i+n):
            temp1.append((line[0][j], line[1][j]))
        main_category.append(temp1)
        temp1 = []

    return main_category
```

But I keep getting

```
'line' is not defined
```

I want to use a different data set for this function.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question with a complete [mcve].  You show two functions but not how you call the first one and pass the result to the second one and how it produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
line = read_files(EDUC_A,EDUC_B)
category = create_categories(line)
```

Comment: The problem is when i call the second line you have there it says line is not defined.

Comment: I was calling the wrong variable rather then line i had lines in the function. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach returned values into a variable

like

```
line = read_files(EDUC_A,EDUC_B)
```

so the function can take it as an argument